# Sendle returns unauthorised but working on local machine

Tags: api, sendle

Upon testing Sendle API sandbox it was working on local machine, the API ID and KEY that I used on local and test server are the same. Why is it that the test server, the API returns

```json
{"error":"unauthorised","error_description":"The authorisation details are not valid. Either the Sendle ID or API key are incorrect."}
```

Is it the Sendle Sandbox only works are localhost or local machine?

Comment: Are you using the keys on different servers? Can you show us example cURL commands that you are using (blocking out the uid/key of course) eg for the ping request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, I have to regenerate new API key for Sendle, but still I don't have any idea why's the previous API KEY is not working. But well everything works fine now.